# Strange subfolder "DTAR_08E86330_4835_4B5C_9E5A_61F37AE1A077_DTAR" created in VS2015's UWP solution folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app

I've seen this empty sub folder `DTAR_08E86330_4835_4B5C_9E5A_61F37AE1A077_DTAR` created few times in different solutions (all UWP) and even in default "Blank App (Universal Windows)" project, the problem is - I can't reproduce it intentionally - sooner or later, it is just created, but I don't know why and what was the cause.

[image]

Does anyone have any clue?

PS. Here is my config if that matter:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version **14.0.23107.0** D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework **4.6.01028**
Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA447
Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA447
Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA447
Windows Phone SDK **8.0** - ENU   00322-20000-00000-AA447
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package **1.0**
ASP.NET and Web Tools   **14.0.20626.0**
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   **5.2.30624.0**
Common Azure Tools   **1.5**
GenerateUnitTest   **1.0**
GitHub.VisualStudio   **1.0**
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate **10 EAP 4**   Build 104.0.20151009.190534-EAP4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   **1.4**
NuGet Package Manager   **3.2.0**
P4VS - Perforce Plugin for Visual Studio   **2015.1.105.4164**
PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   **1.2**
SQL Server Data Tools   **14.0.50616.0**
Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   **14.0.23309.00** d14oob

Comment: I don't think it is a problem. My visual studio does the same, I think we should let it live :D

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz, this is surely not a problem and I have no doubts that this happens not only on my machine, but anyway prefer to eliminate any unnecessary empty folders ones and forever and not every times after they have been created, especially with such a weird name :)

Comment: Please post feedback on the MS connect item I just created at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1909707/getting-empty-folder-in-project-root-after-opening-sln-file-dtar-08e86330-4835-4b5c-9e5a-61f37ae1a077-dtar

Comment: @TimFriesen done it twice there, thanks :)

Comment: Never fails. Just started noticing this in VS 2015 Update 2. Never had this problem with Update 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be (finally) fixed in recent [Visual Studio Update 3 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs) (works for me at least).

Also there is another "more permanent" workaround from *EricStj - MSFT* (copy-pasted from his comment to relevant issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1909707/getting-empty-folder-in-project-root-after-opening-sln-file-dtar-08e86330-4835-4b5c-9e5a-61f37ae1a077-dtar)) for those who would prefer to wait for RTM version of this update and have to skip current RC version:

> The fix didn't make it into Update 2. It should come out in Update 3.
>   To workaround you can copy this file replace this file "**C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v5.0\GlobalDTARSettings.proj**"
>   with the version from here:
>   https://gist.github.com/ericstj/b40dd3846c3faec5ea1ba55fce64d1f8.

Answer (score 20):

There's actually an [issue filed on Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1909707/getting-empty-folder-in-project-root-after-opening-sln-file-dtar-08e86330-4835-4b5c-9e5a-61f37ae1a077-dtar), which is currently reviewed by Microsoft. So brings in some room for the reasonable suspicion that this is a bug of Visual Studio 2015.

There is also a workaround available:

> Posted by DaisyDave on 12/15/2015 at 2:40 AM
>   Opening solutions from within the IDE stops these folders appearing.

Comment: Already voted twice for connect issue a few days after posted this question here (there is also back link to this question in comments there). But thanks for workaround!

Comment: OK, I'm gonna mark this as an answer since the root cause seems to be indeed in VS2015 or one of its component and, thus, could be fixed only by Visual Studio team (and the workaround is working for me fine, thanks you!). Crossing fingers that they review the connect issues from time to time :)

Comment: Another workaround (until Visual Studio 2015 Update 3): https://github.com/stjeong/NoDtarVisualStudioVersionSelector

Comment: @SeongTaeJeong you must be _really_ hate this folder so much that end up writing an app to launch the VS2015. Thanks anyway, hopefully Update 3 will fix this permanently.

Comment: Thanks @SeongTaeJeong for this "pre-Update 3" fix, this really helps to... keep MS reputation high :) Now I wonder what DTAR stands for anyway?

Answer (score 2):

In general I open solutions from Windows Explorer rather than from within Visual Studio.  If you're like me the Connect issue mentioned in Andreas' answer has a second workaround, for opening the solution from Windows Explorer:

> Posted by Dee Key on 3/4/2016 at 11:22 AM 
>   From the Windows File Explorer right-click on the solution file and Open with Visual Studio 2015.